# vba access get data from list box and store in an array

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba

Before I look any further on the internet to try and solve this, is actually possible to do this:

There are two list-boxes with data been displayed. The first list-box shows results from a SQL query. i.e. bus, cab, plane, lorry. The user can select certain data and then add it to listbox2. listbox2 could have the following data: bus, cab, plane in it. what I am trying to do is this:

None of the data has been selected, when an export button is clicked, it loops through listbox2, gets the data from the list-box (Bus, Cab, Plane) and stores it in an array, what I want to do next, is query it in a SQL statement to get the results back to be exported to excel. I can do the SQL part and exporting.

I thought it I would be able to do the code for this, but the amount of different loops and other methods I try it complains. I can get it to count how many rows there are in listbox2, but not pull the data from it.

Looking on the internet the majority of information I seem to find is when it requires data to be selected first - and very little that is based on vba in access, as VBA/VBA Excel is different from the VBA in access so I have found (Urgh)

I'm not expecting someone to give me a coded solution to this, I just want to know before I waste any more time, is this actually possible to achieve?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But use recordsets and not arrays to make it easier for yourself.

Comment: If only selected data is added from listbox1 to listbox2 by just sending the value to listbox2, how would using a recordset then help me select all the data from listbox2? surely the recordset is only useful when putting the data into listbox 1, as the recordset then becomes redundant after its populated listbox1?

Comment: There are pros and cons. Hard to tell without your applications but you can easily browse for how to retrieve selected or all items of a listbox.